# Under the new FB Notifications API, is my app. responsible for cleaning up notifications after they are read?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I am interested in using the new Facebook Notifications API announced on Aug. 31, 2012.

It looks very straightforward to implement, however, I have one question.

With app. requests (which previously, were the only user-to-user communication you could do), it was required to send a HTTP DELETE to remove the app request from Facebook, presumably after the target user clicked on the app. request on the notification jewel.

It's not in the documentation, but I wanted to double check to see if there is any similar cleanup required for notifications sent using the new notifications API, after they are acted upon?

Many thanks,
Wes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as far as I know notifications are 'fire and forget' - you don't need to 'accept' or 'reject' a notification (which is the reason your app needs to delete processed user-user requests), the user simply decides whether or not to act on it - if they don't there's nothing your app needs to do.